# JavaFX mouse event Throwing Exception

Tags: exception, button, javafx, onclick

I Have this code, It uses JavaFX Controls, the Code "fi.setOnAction(e -> fi.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00C275;"));" is supposed to Change the Color of the Button fi, But Doesn't work(Throws Exception), but Interestingly it works after All other Code except for button and the setOnAction is removed :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;


public class Medow extends Application {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    launch(arg);
}

public void start(Stage primarystage) {
    primarystage.setTitle("Medow");
    primarystage.setResizable(false);

    // Label l = new Label("Hello");
    // setXY( 0, 0, l);

    Image image = new Image("/modified/user.jpg");
    ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
    iv1.setImage(image);
    iv1.setFitWidth(93.75);
    iv1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    //iv1.setX(75);
    //iv1.setY(75);


    Circle c = new Circle(46.875, 46.875, 46.875, Color.BLUE); // Previously it was 75, 75 - after adding image the Circle Moves Down, and changing it to 93.75/2 = 46.875 fixes this.
    iv1.setClip(c);




    VBox v1 = new VBox(iv1); // Upper Left VBox - inside vb
    v1.setMinHeight(170);
    v1.setPadding(new Insets(28.125, 0, 0, 28.125));

    Label fa = new Label("Farming");
    fa.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #969696; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    fa.setPadding(new Insets(5, 0, 10, 10));


    //fi.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #606365; -fx-text-fill: #ffffff; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    ImageView fiv = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/map.png"));
    fiv.setFitHeight(20);
    fiv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    Button fi = new Button("Farm", fiv); // Farm Button
    fi.setPadding(new Insets(7.5, 65, 7.5, 20)); // It would be more Efficient to use HBox inside Button
    fi.setGraphicTextGap(10);


    ImageView crv = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/crop.png"));
    crv.setFitHeight(20);
    crv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    Button cr = new Button( "Crop", crv); // Crop Button
    cr.setGraphicTextGap(10);
    cr.setPadding(new Insets(7.5, 67, 7.5, 20));

    ImageView rfv = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/rain.png"));
    rfv.setFitHeight(20);
    rfv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    Button rf = new Button("Rainfall", rfv); // Rainfall Button
    rf.setPadding(new Insets(7.5, 50, 7.5, 20));
    rf.setGraphicTextGap(10);

    ImageView mov = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/drop.png"));
    mov.setFitHeight(20);
    mov.setPreserveRatio(true);
    Button mo = new Button("Moisture", mov); // Moisture
    mo.setPadding(new Insets(7.5, 40, 7.5, 20));
    mo.setGraphicTextGap(10);

    ImageView evv = new ImageView(new Image("/modified/cal.png"));
    evv.setFitHeight(20);
    evv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    Button ev = new Button("Events", evv); //Events
    ev.setPadding(new Insets( 7.5, 55, 7.5, 20));
    ev.setGraphicTextGap(10);


    cr.setId("lp");
    rf.setId("lp");
    mo.setId("lp");
    ev.setId("lp");
    fi.setId("lp");

    changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(cr);
    changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(rf);
    changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(mo);
    changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(ev);
    changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(fi);

     /* fi.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        fi.setStyle("")
    }); */

    fi.setOnAction(e -> fi.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00C275;"));

    /*
    changeBackgroundOnClickUsingBinding(fi);
    changeBackgroundOnClickUsingBinding(cr);
    changeBackgroundOnClickUsingBinding(mo);
    changeBackgroundOnClickUsingBinding(ev);
    changeBackgroundOnClickUsingBinding(rf);
     */

    VBox v2 = new VBox( fa, fi, cr, rf, mo, ev); // Lower Left VBox - inside vb
    v2.setPadding(new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0));

    VBox vb = new VBox(v1, v2); // Left Outer Most VBox
    vb.setMaxWidth(150);
    vb.setMinWidth(150);
    vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #454851;");
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setLeft(vb);
    Scene sc = new Scene(bp, 800, 500);
    sc.getStylesheets().add(Medow.class.getResource("all.css").toExternalForm()); // Adding all.css
    primarystage.setScene(sc);
    primarystage.show();

}
public void setXY(double x, double y, Control o){
    o.setLayoutX(x);
    o.setLayoutY(y);
}

 /*  public void butStyle(Control... b1){
    for(Control b : b1){
    //b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: :#606365;");
    }
} */

private void changeBackgroundOnHoverUsingBinding(Node node) { // Function To Change Button Color on Hover
    node.styleProperty().bind(
            Bindings
                    .when(node.hoverProperty())
                    .then(
                            new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: #373940;")
                    )
                    .otherwise(
                            new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: #454851;")
                    )
    );
}



}
```

Here is the Exception it is Throwing :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Button.style : A bound value cannot be set.
        at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:140)
        at javafx.scene.Node$4.set(Node.java:1101)
        at javafx.scene.Node$4.set(Node.java:1095)
        at javafx.scene.Node.setStyle(Node.java:1073)
        at Medow$1.handle(Medow.java:121)
        at Medow$1.handle(Medow.java:116)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Button.style : A bound value cannot be set.
        at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:140)
        at javafx.scene.Node$4.set(Node.java:1101)
        at javafx.scene.Node$4.set(Node.java:1095)
        at javafx.scene.Node.setStyle(Node.java:1073)
        at Medow$1.handle(Medow.java:121)
        at Medow$1.handle(Medow.java:116)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. The error is not caused by the code you posted, but other code in your application. Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace tells you the problem:

> Button.style : A bound value cannot be set.

i.e. you have bound the style property with

```
node.styleProperty().bind(...
```

and then you try to call

```
fi.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00C275;")
```

To fix this, you either need to unbind the style property before setting it in the handler (in which case it will no longer change color when the mouse hovers/unhovers over it), or your binding needs to accommodate the logic of having been pressed. Which approach you use depends on what functionality you want.